# How to turn a <section> with contents into a link that changes color on hover

Tags: css, html

I have six `<sections>` that are all rows within a flexbox wrapper. Flex-direction is set to column. Each `<section>` (row) has 3 `<spans>`, one `<img>`, one `<i>` and a `<time>` element, which are aligned within each `<section>` using position relative/absolute, using distances from the edges of the `<section>` element. I want to make entire `<section>` a link so that when a user mouses over it, the background color changes.

What's the best way to do this? I had considered making the section an `<a>` element and displaying it as a block but am unsure if this is even possible.

```
<section class="conversations-history-section">
     <span class="conversations-history-section-row-selected"></span>
     <img class="conversations-history-section-row-image"     src="assets/images/profileimg1.png" alt="img">
    <span class="conversations-history-section-row-user">
      <span class="conversations-history-section-row-status online"></span>
      <span class="conversations-history-section-row-name active">Lucile B. Nash</span>
      <span class="conversations-history-section-row-location">Vancouver, BC</span>
    </span>
    <time class="conversations-history-section-row-date">8:48 AM</time>
    <i class="fa fa-e1-message-success conversations-history-section-row-message">   </i>
    <span class="conversations-history-section-row-snippet">Hey, it was really good to see you over the weekend, I look forward to...</span>
</section>

.conversations-history-section {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 140px;
  max-height: 140px;
  width: 400px;
  color: $e1-conversations-history-section-text;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $e1-body-1px-line;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-selected {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 140px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: $e1-conversations-history-section-selected;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-selected.not {
  background-color: $e1-conversations-history-wrapper-bg;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-user {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 50%;
  top: 20px;
  left: 90px;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-image {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 29px;
  top: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-status {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 8px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-status.online {
  background-color: $e1-conversations-history-section-status-online;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-status.offline {
  background-color: $e1-conversations-history-section-status-offline;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-name {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0px;
  left: 16px;
  color: $e1-conversations-history-section-user-name;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-name.active {
  color: $e1-conversations-history-section-user-name-active;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-location {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 20px;
  left: 16px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-date {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 24px;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-message {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 24px;
  bottom: 24px;
  color: $e1-conversations-history-section-row-message;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-message.error {
  color: $e1-conversations-history-section-row-message-error;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-snippet {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  left: 24px;
  bottom: 24px;
}
```

Comment: and the code is...?

Comment: Do you really need it to be a `link` (i.e. to be clickable and navigate the user somewhere)? Or just to change color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to wrap the `section` in `a`  and most likely make that `a` a block level element.

```css
a {
  /* optional */
  display: block
}
a:hover {
  background: red
}
.conversations-history-section {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 140px;
  max-height: 140px;
  width: 400px;
  color: $e1-conversations-history-section-text;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $e1-body-1px-line;
}
.conversations-history-section-row-selected {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 140px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: $e1-conversations-history-section-selected;
}
.conversations-history-section-row-selected.not {
  background-color: $e1-conversations-history-wrapper-bg;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <section class="conversations-history-section">
    <span class="conversations-history-section-row-selected"></span>
    <img class="conversations-history-section-row-image" src="assets/images/profileimg1.png" alt="img">
    <span class="conversations-history-section-row-user">
      <span class="conversations-history-section-row-status online"></span>
    <span class="conversations-history-section-row-name active">Lucile B. Nash</span>
    <span class="conversations-history-section-row-location">Vancouver, BC</span>
    </span>
    <time class="conversations-history-section-row-date">8:48 AM</time>
    <i class="fa fa-e1-message-success conversations-history-section-row-message">   </i>
    <span class="conversations-history-section-row-snippet">Hey, it was really good to see you over the weekend, I look forward to...</span>
  </section>
</a>
```

If you don't want to link the `section` anywhere, then you can just :hover the `section` instead without adding extra HTML.

```css
section:hover {
  background: red
}
.conversations-history-section {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 140px;
  max-height: 140px;
  width: 400px;
  color: $e1-conversations-history-section-text;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $e1-body-1px-line;
}
.conversations-history-section-row-selected {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 140px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: $e1-conversations-history-section-selected;
}
.conversations-history-section-row-selected.not {
  background-color: $e1-conversations-history-wrapper-bg;
}
```

```html
<section class="conversations-history-section">
    <span class="conversations-history-section-row-selected"></span>
    <img class="conversations-history-section-row-image" src="assets/images/profileimg1.png" alt="img">
    <span class="conversations-history-section-row-user">
      <span class="conversations-history-section-row-status online"></span>
    <span class="conversations-history-section-row-name active">Lucile B. Nash</span>
    <span class="conversations-history-section-row-location">Vancouver, BC</span>
    </span>
    <time class="conversations-history-section-row-date">8:48 AM</time>
    <i class="fa fa-e1-message-success conversations-history-section-row-message">   </i>
    <span class="conversations-history-section-row-snippet">Hey, it was really good to see you over the weekend, I look forward to...</span>
  </section>
```

Comment: I did not realize it was that simple, thanks, implementing now.

Comment: with html5 is that simple :)

Comment: Remember that this will do nothing for keyboard users.

Comment: every `:hover` action won't do nothing for keyboard users, not just this, unless `tabindex` is in use or the markup is well structured.

Comment: @Dippas Thanks for additional option. I do want to link the section. Just as a side curiosity, do you se anything wrong with how I've positioned the elements? I've only been doing this a couple weeks. Thanks!

Comment: @LiveWithPassion maybe this could be done differently , but this would be a broad question/answer. :)

Comment: @Dippas oh noes, I'd hate to think I've been doing it wrong 

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a valid solution to transform your section into an `<a>` and make it act as a block :

```
.container a {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Matthieu Schaeffer's answer, I've done something like this (in plain HTML rather the more general XML, but it should work the same).

```css
a.conversations-history-section {
  display: block;
  background-color: green:
}
.conversations-history-section:hover {
  background-color: blue:
}
```

When you hover over the section, the background should turn from green to blue, or whatever colors you want.

Just one warning: make your that your schema allows putting all those elements (e.g., `<time>`) inside your `<a>` element. If your XML doesn't match your schema, the browser may do strange things. I'd recommend using an XML validator (online or downloadable).

NOTE: My code does not obey the XHTML schema, e.g., block-level elements `<p>` and `<ul>` inside an `<a>`. It works as shown, but when I tried putting a second-level `<a>` inside one of the paragraphs, only part of the text had the correct background.

This is based on the "salmon book": Cascading Style Sheets from O'Reilly, page 53 (section title "Pseudo-Class Selectors", subsection "Dynamic pseudo-classes")

Here is the code I used to test this:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>title</title>
<style type="text/css">
a.section {
    display: block;
    background-color: #8f8;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
.section:hover {
    background-color: #88f;
}
a.section a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: red;
    display: inline;
}
a.section a:visited {
    display: inline;
    color: silver;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="all">
<a href="#" class="section">
<p>This is the first paragraph<br/>
And a second line.
</p>
<ul>
<li>abc</li>
<li>def</li>
<li>ghi</li>
<li>xyz</li>
</ul>
<p>This is the second paragraph
</p>
</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, all you really need is this:

```
section:hover{background-color:wheat;}
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/8gu1g64c/)</kbd>

```css
section:hover{background-color:wheat;}

.conversations-history-section {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 140px;
  max-height: 140px;
  width: 400px;
  color: $e1-conversations-history-section-text;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $e1-body-1px-line;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-selected {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 140px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: $e1-conversations-history-section-selected;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-selected.not {
  background-color: $e1-conversations-history-wrapper-bg;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-user {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 50%;
  top: 20px;
  left: 90px;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-image {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 29px;
  top: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-status {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 8px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-status.online {
  background-color: $e1-conversations-history-section-status-online;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-status.offline {
  background-color: $e1-conversations-history-section-status-offline;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-name {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0px;
  left: 16px;
  color: $e1-conversations-history-section-user-name;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-name.active {
  color: $e1-conversations-history-section-user-name-active;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-location {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 20px;
  left: 16px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-date {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 24px;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-message {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 24px;
  bottom: 24px;
  color: $e1-conversations-history-section-row-message;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-message.error {
  color: $e1-conversations-history-section-row-message-error;
}

.conversations-history-section-row-snippet {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  left: 24px;
  bottom: 24px;
}
```

```html
<section class="conversations-history-section">
     <span class="conversations-history-section-row-selected"></span>
     <img class="conversations-history-section-row-image"     src="assets/images/profileimg1.png" alt="img">
    <span class="conversations-history-section-row-user">
      <span class="conversations-history-section-row-status online"></span>
      <span class="conversations-history-section-row-name active">Michael Buble</span>
      <span class="conversations-history-section-row-location">Vancouver, BC</span>
    </span>
    <time class="conversations-history-section-row-date">7:59 AM</time>
    <i class="fa fa-e1-message-success conversations-history-section-row-message">   </i>
    <span class="conversations-history-section-row-snippet">I really enjoyed those singing contests at the PNE every summer..</span>
</section>
<section class="conversations-history-section">
     <span class="conversations-history-section-row-selected"></span>
     <img class="conversations-history-section-row-image"     src="assets/images/profileimg1.png" alt="img">
    <span class="conversations-history-section-row-user">
      <span class="conversations-history-section-row-status online"></span>
      <span class="conversations-history-section-row-name active">Michael J Fox</span>
      <span class="conversations-history-section-row-location">Burnaby, BC</span>
    </span>
    <time class="conversations-history-section-row-date">8:08 AM</time>
    <i class="fa fa-e1-message-success conversations-history-section-row-message">   </i>
    <span class="conversations-history-section-row-snippet">Christopher Lloyd was better on Taxi, but I sure had great times at Burnaby Central...</span>
</section>
<section class="conversations-history-section">
     <span class="conversations-history-section-row-selected"></span>
     <img class="conversations-history-section-row-image"     src="assets/images/profileimg1.png" alt="img">
    <span class="conversations-history-section-row-user">
      <span class="conversations-history-section-row-status online"></span>
      <span class="conversations-history-section-row-name active">Lucile B. Nash</span>
      <span class="conversations-history-section-row-location">Vancouver, BC</span>
    </span>
    <time class="conversations-history-section-row-date">8:48 AM</time>
    <i class="fa fa-e1-message-success conversations-history-section-row-message">   </i>
    <span class="conversations-history-section-row-snippet">Hey, it was really good to see you over the weekend, I look forward to...</span>
</section>
```